# Issue with reading file content

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I have a file which contains text. I read line by line of the entire file and append to a string object. But when i get the final string print out i am not getting the whole file content. I am sure it is due to the presence of special characters like '\n', '\r', '\t', etc.

here is my sample code:

```
// Read lines until end of file (null) is reached
do
{
    line = ""; 
    inputStream->read_line(line);

    cout<<"\n "<<line;//here i get the content of each line
    fileContent.append(line);// here i am appending
}while(line.compare("") != 0);
```

Comment: Show more code, like where you declare `inputStream` and `fileContent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to read a file into memory in C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <string> lines;
    ifstream ifs( "myfile.txt" );
    string line;
    while( getline( ifs, line ) ) {
         lines.push_back( line );
    }
    // do something with lines
}
```

Comment: @iSight Not with my compiler it doesn't. What error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, i need to pass const char* in ifs constructor.

Comment: @iSight I don't know - you haven't posted enough for me to be able to tell.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll have to show more code for me to know what your problem is.

If you’re reading the entire file into a single string, this is the method I usually use:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

std::string read_file(const char *file_name)
{
    std::filebuf fb;

    if(!fb.open(file_name, std::ios_base::in))
    {
        // error.
    }

    return std::string(
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(&fb),
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
}
```